# A question related to Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\gamma$ be a finite measure on the collection $M$ of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\gamma$ has the property that $\gamma(E)=0$ for all measurable sets $E$ such that Lebesgue measure of $E$ is zero.

Show that there exists a non-negative $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\gamma(E)=\int_{E}g$.

I'm trying to prove this claim without making use of Radon-Nikodym Theorem (using the hint to consider $G(x)=\gamma(-\infty,x]$ and using the fact that $G$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$), but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are you allowed to use? Proving that absolutely continuous measures are all integration against some function is a _lot_ of the content of the radon-nikodym theorem, so you more or less have to prove it if you want to do this without citing it. If we have a better idea of what you can use, we'll have a better idea of how to help ^_^

Comment: To my knowledge there is no "simple" proof of this fact that would avoid the usual proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 At least for half open intervals, this does seem to follow from the characterization of absolute continuity as being an indefinite integral

Comment: @operatorerror, characterizing absolute continuity of a distribution function as the existence of a function $g$ so that $\gamma((-\infty,x] ) = \int_{-\infty}^x g(x)dm(x) $ is effectively assuming the conclusion of the Radon-Nykodym theorem, but if you are willing to assume this then I guess it is still a nontrivial exercise to show that it holds for arbitrary measurable $E$, so maybe that is what they are going for!

Comment: @LostStatistician18 agreed on the final point (after all, it's the Radon Nikodym theorem in the end), but I thought this characterization of absolute continuity could be proved independently (and with less work than the Radon-Nikodym theorem) by the FTC, but I don't have my copy of rudin with me and could be wrong